# How to sync Sharepoint Online (Office 365) with MS Office 2016 Pro OneDrive for Business?

Tags: microsoft-office

1. I am going to the SharePoint Online library I want to sync.
2. There I click on the sync button, and select sync now.
3. This opens the OneDrive for Business "Sync the library..." dialog. Select sync now
4. OFB says, getting ready to sync and after a few seconds "We could not sync this library."

As an additional hint it tells me:

> this libarary can no longer be synced using this application. To sync these files, use the latest OneDrive application.

And a link to get the app. But when I get this version, it will not install with the reason that I've allready got a newer version installed.

I cannot deinstall the OFB sync client seperately, because it's a part of the Office installation.

How can I make my PC sync with the sharepoint folders using OFB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. You need to set up sharepoint for the new Onedrive:
[Here is your answer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-users-to-sync-SharePoint-files-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-22e1f635-fb89-49e0-a176-edab26f69614?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)